# Get the value of textbox when the radiobutton is checked and change the value of radiobutton based on textbox value

Tags: jquery

How do I get the value of textbox and put it on the value of radio button when the radiobutton is checked. This is not my code but to make it short I illustrate like this for example:

```
<input type="radio" name="correct" value="">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" value="Mark">

<input type="radio" name="correct" value="">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" value="Bill">

<input type="radio" name="correct" value="">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" value="Mia">
```

Now, I want to store the value of radio button based on textbox value.
Thank you in advance!.

Comment: Add some code that you tried, I don't think someone will do the code for you.

Comment: Sorry sir but I don't know what is the logic behind that and I don't know if it is possible to do that. I'm not too good in programming sorry sir @Learner

Comment: You don't need to be good, just to open any website with jquery tutorials and after one day you will learn to try something out besides doing nothing...

Comment: I tried to search that question but I don't see any solution for that. So, I try to ask question here. Thank you sir :)

Comment: You will in 90% never find what are you looking for but you will find in 100% how to get value from input and how to add value to radio button. Sometimes you need to search more and collect data to complete your needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*First of all I didnt understand your question, But I hope this is what you looking for*

Waiting for your reply

```
  function getTextValue(val){
    //In onclick function I get the value of text box and assign it to the respective radio button
       var rad =   $("#txt"+val).val();
       var txt = $("#rd"+val).val(rad);
       alert(rad);
       alert(txt);
    }



<input type="radio" name="correct" onclick="getTextValue('1')" id="rd1" value="">
<input type="text" class="form-control"  id="txt1" name="name[]" value="Mark">

<input type="radio" name="correct" onclick="getTextValue('2')" id="rd2" value="">
<input type="text" class="form-control"  id="txt2" name="name[]" value="Bill">

<input type="radio" name="correct" onclick="getTextValue('3')" id="rd3" value="">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt3" name="name[]" value="Mia">
```

Comment: sir I update my question. Sorry for wrong question. Get the value of textbox when the radiobutton is checked and change the value of radiobutton based on textbox value

Comment: Then sure mate, Above code will work for you did you face any issue

Comment: Now check friend I make some edit and this will work for you sure and if its work then approve my answer

Comment: Sorry sir. I try to call the rd1 but the value of rd1 is null alert($("#rd1").val());

Comment: could you explain your issue

Comment: I need to call the radiobutton in php code. So that I need the value of radiobutton. Like this : correc = $_POST["correct"];

Comment: you doesnt assign any value to your radio button so its alert null, I make some edit in my post look for that

Comment: I make some changes in my post please have a look

Comment: when alerting the alert(txt) is says that [object Object]

Comment: text or txt mate??

Comment: Did you inspect and check the value of your radio button??

Comment: Thanks! It works Sir. Thnk you for the time and effort sir

Answer (score 1):

Based on the question, this could be a possible solution, but again, this is just a simple working example. Try implementing this method on your problem.

---

**Solution:**

We can use the `onChange` method and from the input element where the click happened, we get the previous element(radio button) then set the value to that of the input using the `val()` method!

```js
function initialize() {
  $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
    $(this).prev().val($(this).val());
  });
}
initialize();
$('input[type="text"]').on("change", function() {
  $(this).prev().val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="correct" value="">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" value="Mark">

<input type="radio" name="correct" value="">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" value="Bill">

<input type="radio" name="correct" value="">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" value="Mia">
```

Comment: Thank you sir. But in my form there is a lot of textbox.

Comment: @YadYoung No Problem, Thanks for your time!